# Web Services: how to get/save Web Part on a page

Tags: 2007, web-services, javascript, jquery

The WebPartPages Web service includes actions to get or save Web Part properties (GetWebPart, SaveWebPart). Both require a unique identifier called storageKey.

When using Web services on the client side (JavaScript/jQuery), how can I retrieve this storageKey?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Storage key is a guid. The value of it is the same as the value of WebPartID attribute of the div representing the web part.

Comment: I tried in SP Foundation and it didn't work for me. When I use WebPartID as storageKey, I get the following message: The operation could not be completed because the Web Part is not on this page.

Comment: Try calling SaveWebPart() Web Service method and see if the return value matches the WebPartID attribute on the div. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774839(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This Web Service has horrible documentation, even worse than the others. As I remember when I played around with it, I could get information about the Web Parts on the page with GetWebPartPage first.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your web part ID to you javascript when the page is loaded.

Try

```
Guid ((Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager)WebPartManager).GetStorageKey(this);
```

As for saving your web part properties, instead of going through SOAP you could create a service that uses the SPLimitedWebPartManager using the storage key.

Something like this should work.

```
        using (SPWeb web = new SPSite(webUrl).OpwnWeb()){
    using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = GetLimitedWebPartManager(PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(web) ? PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb.DefaultPage.Url : web.RootFolder.WelcomePage, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
    WebPart part = manager.WebParts[storageKey];
//Do web part stuff.
    }
    }
```